# Regexp_extract in spark2.2.0 with scala throws error

Tags: scala, apache-spark, bigdata

My code is follows,

`val y = Seq(("100-200"),("300-400"),("500-600")).toDF("numbersData")
          .withColumn("extractedData",regexp_extract($"numbersData","(\d+)-(\d+)",1))`

 I want output with 'extractedData' column as,

`100
   300
   500`

But I am getting error as,

`error: invalid escape character
          .withColumn("extractedData",regexp_extract($"numbersData","(\d+)-(\d+)",1))
                                                                       ^`

Please Guide

Comment: Have to work with double escape:  "(\\d+)-(\\d+)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to escape the backslash. Try this

```
scala> val y = Seq(("100-200"),("300-400"),("500-600")).toDF("numbersData").withColumn("extractedData",regexp_extract($"numbersData","(\\d+)-(\\d+)",1)).show()
+-----------+-------------+
|numbersData|extractedData|
+-----------+-------------+
|    100-200|          100|
|    300-400|          300|
|    500-600|          500|
+-----------+-------------+

y: Unit = ()

scala>
```

Comment: Thank You! very much  stack0114106.

Answer (score 3):

Using double-backslash in your Regex pattern `"(\\d+)-(\\d+)"`, as pointed out by others, will fix the problem – although there is no need for Regex with simplistic pattern like this.  Instead, you could use `split`:

```
df.withColumn("extractedData", split($"numbersData", "-")(0)).show
// +-----------+-------------+
// |numbersData|extractedData|
// +-----------+-------------+
// |    100-200|          100|
// |    300-400|          300|
// |    500-600|          500|
// +-----------+-------------+
```

Note that both the `Regex` and `split` solutions will result in a StringType column.  If necessary, you can apply `cast("Int")` as well to make the new column of IntegerType.

Comment: Thank you! Leo C,your answer helped me to look at problem through different angle.